# Amp Script to convert decimal value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In date extension there is a text field with name CRT and it contains a decimal value 53.8888889998899988

I want to get an output up to two decimal places that is 53.88.

I am trying to use FormatNumber but when I preview it, I am getting the following error

```
*The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.
 Function Call: FormatNumber(@CTR1,D2,en-US)
 Attribute or Field Name: D2*
```

Please see below code:

```
%%[
    var @lookupValue
    var @countrow
    var @i
    var @rowCount

    set @lookupValue = "1"
    set @countrow = lookupRows("Total Sent Last 7 days Extract","booleanvalue", @lookupValue)
    SET @i = 1
      set @rowCount = row(@countrow,@i)
      set @CTR1 = field(@rowCount,"CRT")
      set @CTR1 = FormatNumber(@CTR1,D2,en-US)   
      ]%%
      <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; max-width:650px; padding:10px; display:block; border:1px dashed red;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <strong>No of Emails Opened: </strong> %%=field(@rowCount,"TotalEmailOpens")=%%<br>
            <strong>CTR: </strong> %%=v(@CTR1)=%%%<br>


          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: you need double quotes around the D2 and en-US and also, I would recommend using `Format(@CTR1, "N2", "en-US") instead.

Comment: Did you need it to round up/down, or do you want it cut off at a specific decimal place?

Comment: @Gortonington, thank you for looking into this. N2 works perfectly. I would want to round the decimal. Strangely link (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatNumber.htm) does not ask to use the double quotes. MC should update the documentation. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes around the D2 and en-US inside of your call otherwise it assumes they are calls for variables/fields.

Also, I would recommend using `Format(@CTR1, "N2", "en-US")` instead - this will allow it to format numbers stored as strings as well as any that are stored as numbers/decimals.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using FixePoint (F2) as the format type within the [FormatNumber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatNumber.htm) AMPscript function.

Example:

```
%%=FormatNumber(53.8888889998899988, "F2", "en-US")=%%
```

Result: **`53.89`**

Comment: Thank you, Brad, for looking into this issue. FormatNumber(@CTR1,"N2","en-US") is working fine for me.

Comment: no worries. Could you add your solution to the post and mark as accepted and resolved. thank you

Comment: How to add the solution?